# Does circumcision require an orthodox Mohel?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, brit-milah, heterodox

Consider a case of a Jewish-born child who was circumcised by a non-orthodox or non-Jewish person (say with a circumcision clamp by a doctor - where the doctor was just thinking about a surgical procedure, but the parents did it for Jewish reasons and not because it prevents disease or another secular consideration). It was done on or after 8 days old.

Is Hatafas Dam Bris (a pinprick of blood) required subsequently? Or does it not really matter - after the fact - who did it, just that it was done on or after the right time?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30079/3

Comment: Were all three parts of Halachik cicumcision performed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Maimonides** [says no](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2602.htm), though it is preferable that the mohel be a Jewish adult male. A Gentile should not preform the circumcision, but if he does, it need not be repeated (I assume by way of drawing blood). **Shulkhan Arukh** [agrees](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9732&st=&pgnum=432&hilite=).

So for **Sephardic** Jews, there is no problem as long as the mohel is Jewish, and it is preferred that he not be a Gentile.

**However the Remah** [argues](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9732&st=&pgnum=432&hilite=), saying that if non Jew, or even a Jew that has forsaken the Torah entire or even just the commandment of circumcision, performs the circumcision, a drawing of blood must be done.

So for **Ashkenazic** Jews, the Mohel must be an Orthodox Jew.

One wishing to satisfy **all** opinions would have to use an Orthodox mohel.

Comment: This all assumes that there was blood at the time of the procedure. Certain clamp-based techniques don't have any bleeding and would need Hatafat Dam Brit even if performed by a Jew.